# Is a quotient of two series of functions increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, monotone-functions

Let $x>0$. Can we say something about the monotonicity of

$$f(x) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x+xk} \left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^k} \quad?$$

I strongly believe that the function $f(x)$ should be (strictly) increasing - at least it is what a plot of $f$ suggests - but I have no clue how to prove it, or even approach it. I tried differentiating it but I got nowhere...

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

My usual naive plodding.

I get that
$f(x)$
is increasing.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+x+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}\\
&= \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+x(k+1)} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}\\
&= \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k-1}}\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k}}\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\dfrac{1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k}}\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\left(\dfrac{1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^k}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k}}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k}}\right)\\
&= \dfrac{x}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+xk} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k-1}}\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{y}{1-y}k} \left(y\right)^{k-1}}
\quad y = x/(1+x), x=y/(1-y), 0 < y < 1
\qquad (*)\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1-y}{1-y+yk} y^{k-1}}\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1-y}{1+y(k-1)} y^{k-1}}\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1-y}{1+yk} y^k}\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{(1-y)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+yk} y^k}\\
&= y+\dfrac{1}{(1-y)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{1+yk} \right)}\\
\end{array}
$

Since $x$ and $y$
are monotonic
in the same direction,
and
$\dfrac{d}{dy}\dfrac{y^k}{1 + y k} 
= \dfrac{y^{k - 1} ((k - 1) k y + k)}{(k y + 1)^2}
\gt 0
$
for
$y > 0, k \ge 1$,
$1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{1+yk}$
is increasing
so
$(1-y)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{1+yk} \right)
$
is decreasing
so
$\dfrac{1}{(1-y)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{1+yk} \right)}
$
is increasing
so
$f(x)$
is increasing.

$(*)$

$y = x/(1+x)$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}
=\dfrac1{(1+x)^2}
\gt 0$

$y+xy=x$

$y=x-xy
=x(1-y)$

$x=\dfrac{y}{1-y}
$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. There is only one step which is not clear to me. I agree that $1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{1+yk}$ is increasing BUT since $1-y$ is decreasing, how do we know that $(1-y)(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{1+yk})$ will be also decreasing?

Comment: Oops. I think you are right. I will have to think on this.